# Build a telegram bot with laravel that saves their chat-id and their ETH Address to database

Tags: php, laravel, bots, telegram

I wish to Build a telegram bot with laravel that saves their chat-id and their ETH Address to database, is there a way around it rather than using Node.js

I've used Google Sheet and a few SDK, like https://github.com/irazasyed/telegram-bot-sdk but couldn't pass the expected results to table

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using the [Botman](https://botman.io/) framework? It supports usage in Laravel projects:

https://botman.io/1.5/installation-laravel